# How to export all Solana accounts with positive balance?

Tags: account, validator

Given access to Solana validator node and `solana` command, how to export a list of all account addresses with positive balance (at the latest block)? Preferably in CSV format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes the [solana CLI utils](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) are available

1. Create a new directory named `ledger`
2. Download genesis and a snapshot (full and incremental if applicable) from the target cluster and move them inside.  Use something like [1] to list available source validators and use a single source for all files
3. Use ledger tool to dump all accounts to JSON and consume however you please

```
solana-ledger-tool --ledger ./ledger accounts --output json
```

---

[1] (requires `jq`)

```
!/usr/bin/env bash

cluster=devnet # one of `localhost`, `devnet`, `testnet`, `mainnet-beta` or custom RPC URL

canonical_snapshot_url() {
  local -r relative_url="${1:?'missing required arg 1: `relative_url`'}"
  url="$(wget -nv --connect-timeout 3 --tries 1 --method HEAD "$relative_url" 2>&1)"
  local -r rc=$?
  if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
    cut -d' ' -f4 <<<"$url"
  fi
  return $rc
}
pids=()
while read RPCHOST; do
  (
    full_url="$(canonical_snapshot_url http://${RPCHOST}/snapshot.tar.bz2)"
    if [[ 0 = $? ]]; then
      gen_url="$(canonical_snapshot_url http://${RPCHOST}/genesis.tar.bz2)"
      out="$gen_url\n$full_url"
      inc_url="$(canonical_snapshot_url http://${RPCHOST}/incremental-snapshot.tar.bz2)"
      if [[ 0 = $? ]]; then
        out+="\n$inc_url"
      fi
      echo -e "$out\n --"
    fi
  ) &
  pids+=($!)
done < <(solana -u "$cluster" gossip --output json | jq -r '.[].rpcHost | select (. != null)')

wait ${pids[*]}
```

Comment: what is genesis?