# JSON RPC get all SPL token holders during specific time

Tags: rpc, spl-token-program, jsonrpc-api, python

I am trying to get all the holders of a specific SPL token during a specific time. I get the `Error: {'code': -32010, 'message': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this PC method unavailable for key'}`
I have tried almost every free and paid RPC provider. Here is my code

```
import requests
import json
import datetime

# Set the endpoint URL for the Solana JSON RPC
endpoint = "INSERT ENDPOINT"

# Set the SPL token mint address
token_mint_address = "INSERT MINT"

# Set the date and time to query for token holders
date_time_str = 'INSERT DATE HERE FORMAT OOOO-00-00 00:00:00'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
timestamp = int(date_time_obj.timestamp())

# Define the JSON-RPC request to get all token accounts for the SPL token at the specified timestamp
json_rpc_request = {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "getProgramAccounts",
  "params": [
    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    {
      "encoding": "jsonParsed",
      "filters": [
        {
          "dataSize": 165
        },
        {
          "memcmp": {
            "offset": 0,
            "bytes": token_mint_address
          }
        },
        {
          "dataSize": 82
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

# Send the JSON-RPC request to the Solana endpoint and get the response
response = requests.post(endpoint, json=json_rpc_request).json()
```

Answer (score 2):

Most RPC providers can't have an index on the token program because there are so many accounts owned by the program.

As a workaround, you could use the `getTokenLargestAccounts` call to get the 20 top accounts for a particular SPL token: https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettokenlargestaccounts

Otherwise, you could use `solana-ledger-tool` against a full snapshot to fetch all of the information, similar to [How to export all Solana accounts with positive balance?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-to-export-all-solana-accounts-with-positive-balance/44#44)

Regarding historical data, it isn't possible to retrieve it by default. You would need to have a separate indexing service to store historical data.  More information at [How do I get historical AccountInfos at timestamp x, y, and z?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-get-historical-accountinfos-at-timestamp-x-y-and-z)